# Axios returns error status code 500 when there is data present

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, store

I am using `Laravel 8`, `VueJS` and `Axios` for my application then every time I try to fetch all records from my database it returns an error with status code 500. Even though when fetching the data using Postman/Insomnia it returns the data without an error.

I tried to empty the table where it fetches the data the error disappears and it returns empty data with status code 200.

**Store Module:**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        courses: [],
        teacher: '',
    },
    getters: {
        allCourses(state) {
            return state.courses
    },
},
actions: {
    async fetchAllCourses({ commit }) {
        const response = await axios.get('teacher/course-management/list')
        console.log(response.data.data)
        commit('SET_COURSES', response.data.data)
    }
},
mutations: {
    SET_COURSES(state, courses) {
        state.courses = courses
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function fetchAllCourses() {
    try {
        $courses = Course::all()->sortBy('id');

        $data = $courses->transform(function ($course) {
            // ! Get teacher id
            $teacherId = $this->user->teacher->id;
            // ! Get teacher name by id
            $teacherName = $this->getTeacherName($teacherId);

            return [
                'id' => $course->id,
                'teacher_id' => $course->teacher_id,
                'teacher' => $teacherName,
                'section' => $course->section,
                'code' => $course->code,
                'status' => $course->status,
                'image' => $course->image,
            ];
        });

        return $this->success('Request success', $data);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $this->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }   
}
```

Comment: HTTP Error 500 is being set on the server side.

Use the chrome devs tools to check that the request from your webpage exactly matches what you have in Postman. 

Most likely there is a difference in the query you are missing.

Comment: You're returning and array before the actual JSON

Comment: @OMiShah I have a success trait method that converts my response data into json

Comment: @OMiShah the `return [...]` is inside the `transform` callback. That is not the return value for the controller method

Comment: What do your Laravel logs say about the error?

Comment: Is there any other way to add the teacher name when returning `Course::all()` collection because the way it is now it only returns `teacher_id` which is the foreign key.

Comment: @Phil, yeah sorry I missed that !!

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved.

```
public function fetchAllCourses() {
        try {
            $courses = Course::all()->sortBy('id');
    
            $data = $courses->transform(function ($course) {
                return [
                    'id' => $course->id,
                    'teacher_id' => $course->teacher_id,
                    'teacher' => $this->getTeacherName($course->teacher_id),
                    'section' => $course->section,
                    'code' => $course->code,
                    'status' => $course->status,
                    'image' => $course->image,
                ];
            });
    
            return $this->success('Request success', $data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        }   
    }
```

Comment: I really don't see how removing the _teacher_ lookup fixes the problem for Axios when it worked in Postman

Comment: From my first code I was getting the `$teacherId` of the current logged-in user instead of `teacher_id` from every `$course` in `$courses`.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand how it worked in Postman but not for Axios